# Is only the front-end protection enough to prevent a few additions - with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Let's say there is a button (ADD BUTTON) to add a blog. Adding is done when the user clicks on this button. But when you click the button several times, a few records are created. To prevent this, I did the method with the javascript below. Do you think this method works fully?

```
 $(function(){
        $('form').on('submit', function () {
            $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', 'true');
        })
    });
```

When I make this code based on id and classes, the user can intervene yes. When I make this code based on ids and classes, the user can intervene yes. But when I write just as above, when the user intervenes in the code, either the form submission is active and it is run in a healthy way.

```
$(function(){
            $('.form-prevent').on('submit', function () {
                $('.btn-prevent').attr('disabled', 'true');
            })
        });
```

Comment: It is a good practice to have some type of check at back-end so that duplicate blog is not created.  Your front-end validation is good, but very easily someone can rewrite this. So better to have both front-end and back-end validation.

Comment: I didn't control that. But it seems that the user cannot interfere with this method. When you right click and say examine.

Comment: See users can interfere with this, as this is easily available to the user. What you have written is fine with normal users, but suppose attacker want to exploit this then the attacker can.

Comment: it should be fixed if you reload the page after submitting your data or empty your form after submitting it.

Comment: also every user with a scriptblocker will be able to send in as many forms as he likes since your javascript wont be executed by his browser